# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.setting' error when start debugging

Tags: python, django, debugging

When i try to start debugging my django project, pycharm raises the error

```
/home/vinc/miniconda3/bin/python /home/vinc/Downloads/pycharm-2018.3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 37987 --file /mnt/7E8A3C928A3C4943/MEGASync/UNI/LM/UNIMORE/3/AWM/mysite/browse/views.py
pydev debugger: process 8451 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 183.5429.31)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vinc/Downloads/pycharm-2018.3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/vinc/Downloads/pycharm-2018.3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/vinc/Downloads/pycharm-2018.3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/vinc/Downloads/pycharm-2018.3.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/mnt/7E8A3C928A3C4943/MEGASync/UNI/LM/UNIMORE/3/AWM/mysite/browse/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from browse.forms import *
  File "/mnt/7E8A3C928A3C4943/MEGASync/UNI/LM/UNIMORE/3/AWM/mysite/browse/forms.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import Comment, Attraction, Image, AttractionTag
  File "/mnt/7E8A3C928A3C4943/MEGASync/UNI/LM/UNIMORE/3/AWM/mysite/browse/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from portal.models import Profile
  File "/mnt/7E8A3C928A3C4943/MEGASync/UNI/LM/UNIMORE/3/AWM/mysite/portal/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 87, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 249, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/vinc/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.setting'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think that there is some configuration problem. 
Here are the
[Python Console settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2ANR.png)

And here is the [debug configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWpIh.png)

What's the problem?

### Edit

wsgi.py

```
import os, sys
from mysite.settings import BASE_DIR

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
sys.path.append("/mnt/7E8A3C928A3C4943/MEGASync/UNI/LM/UNIMORE/3/AWM/mysite")



os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myproject.settings"
```

Comment: show your wsgi file

Comment: did you add app name to installed apps in settings.py file

Comment: The error literally complains about not finding the `mysite.setting` module, while the name generally is `settings`. You seem to have misspelled that in the `Environment Variables` section (`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.setting`) in the [`Run/Debug Configuration` for `views.py`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWpIh.png).